# Mailing list subscription

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have this section on my site the call to action is :

> "Subscribe to my mailing list to be notified of when my full website
>   releases."

How do I collect email addresses and save them to a file (I'm guessing it will require some kind of php or other server side language)

HTML code is below

```
<div class="right">
                <p class='attention'>Website to be released <br>early-mid 2020!</p>
                <form action="mailto" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <input type="text" name='email' id='email' placeholder="your email">
                <button type="submit">Notify Me</button>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very specific to your ask, it will help you save the email ids to a file "data.txt" in your project directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Store form data in .txt file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="right">
        <p class='attention'>Website to be released <br>early-mid 2020!</p>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name='email' id='email' placeholder="your email">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Notify Me</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$data=$_POST['email']. PHP_EOL;
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do I put the php?

Comment: Above code snippet can be put in one single file, EX : 'index.php'.

Comment: So how does it work? I have put the php snippet into index.php and the html in an index.html file and filling out the form does nothing?

Comment: No, you need to put both html and php in 'index.php' file, and spin up the page, hope you have a web server running, if not please check on how to install XAMPP for Apache or turn on IIS. But if you a beginner I would recommend using XAMPP as it would help you in having php,DB and wed server to be install as a package.